# how to receive inner text of a specific node in java android using DocumentBuilder with the XML document attached

Tags: java, android, xml

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fowxd.png)Xml Document

[image]

im trying to receive the child node values of the xml document above, i have tried but cannot seem to get specific node values.

this is my code:

```
            InputStream stream = connect.getInputStream();
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(stream);
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

             System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getTagName());
             System.out.println("Root elements :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());


             NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("PurchaseEntitites");

              System.out.println("===============================================================");

               //do this the old way, because nodeList is not iterable
                for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
                    System.out.println("\nNode Name :" + node.getNodeName());

                 if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                     Element eElement = (Element) node;
                     System.out.println("Employee id : " + eElement.getAttribute("ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites"));

                      System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("rAnnualRate").item(0).getTextContent());


                      }

                         }


            stream.close();

        }
```

Comment: <PurchaseEntitites> tag is child of <ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites> you can not find <ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites> under <PurchaseEntitites> tag. you should correct your xml

Comment: i have replaced,   NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites"); and  System.out.println("Employee id : " + eElement.getAttribute("PurchaseEntitites"));  still doesnt seem to work

Comment: Or does the Xml Document itself need to be altered ?

Comment: can you show output?

Comment: Sure.i have uploaded a picture of the output.